# How to verify each email sent by php mailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm in a situation that I need to verify the sending of the emails submitted by a form. I want to show in the page (it's a test) if the email was sent.

Example:

```
if(!$email){
    echo "email not sent";
} else {
    echo "email sent";
}
```

This is the part of my code that I use to send emails:

page.php

```
$subject = "Hello!";
$html = "<p>Message</p>";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SetFrom('example1@email.com', 'One');

$address = "example1@email.com";
$address2 = "example2@gmail.com";

$mail->AddAddress($address, "receiver1");
$mail->AddAddress($address2, "receiver2"); 

$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->MsgHTML($html);

// I need to verify each email here
```

Comment: PHPMailers own example should show you this... it's simply a matter of checking for errors when sending.

Comment: But how can I do that, Epodax? I saw the example using 1 email, but 2 or more I don't know how to do. Can you help me?

Comment: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail Shows you just exactly what you are asking for, I'm not sure what there is to understand?

Comment: I'll edit the answer

Comment: Just because PHP mailer returns true doesn't mean your mail server has actually sent it.  Even then doesn't mean it has been received neither.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!$mailObject->Send()) {

echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else echo "Message sent!";
```

This error message will only be thrown if there is an error in your connection data, or login credentials, or if there is a server issue.

There is no specific way to verify the email was sent. (So long as the connection is working, the smtp, pop, or imap data is correct then the email will send. Even if the email never arrives at the end point.

Normally an email will eventually be returned to the sender when it fails to reach the recipient. I imagine you could setup some sort of listener that watches for these emails. You still will not get instant feedback in the form of an error, but you can use it to create a failed emails page for the user.

I found a couple relevant links:

[PHPMailer Fails with no error](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/56)

[PHP Reference Guide - PHPMailer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($mail->send()){ 
    echo "Mail sent Successfully"; 
} else{ 
    echo "Mail not Sent.!"; 
}
```

`$mail->send()` function send the mail, so you can check that if the mail is sent or not.!